# I'm unable to run experiments accross subdomains using Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-experiments, content-experiments

I'm currently running an experiment without redirect, using Google Analytics, but I'm running in some issues.

**The case**

I work for a company that has two websites, with two separate brands, selling the same product. Today, we are plaining a merge of the brands, one of the reasons being the low costs of maintanance.

To see how this would affect sales, we are doing an a/b test. The test consists of changing the logo of the sites, and displaying an information about the merge of brands in the variant. The original is the website without changes.

We have some requirements to do it:

- We use a CMS that has no support to the Google Analytics Experiment tag (we get some errors when we install it to the , and are unable to run it)
- We need to run it through all pages of our websites. We have also a subdomain in each site, that the user is redirected to place an order.
- We doesn't have time to wait for the experiment to end for itself. So, we came up with the idea to track the rejection and sales using a duplicate pageview with "/variant" in the url and in the title.

To do that, I used the [Content Experiments without redirects](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZ9_-0hd7UAhUJDJAKHSXdDdwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fsolutions%2Fexperiments-client-side&usg=AFQjCNHxva6BsM9kgSouiWnVb2BLCJrXLA), with the Google Tag Manager.

**Configuration of the Experiment**

1. In Google Tag Manager, I load the Content Experiment Javascript API and define the choosenVariation variable in all pages of both websites and subdirectories.
2. I track the "gtm.load" event, to see when the page finished loading all elements and change the DOM in three ways: changing the logo, adding the content about the merge and add an item to the main menu. All of this, through Javascript.
3. Along with the changes of the DOM, I add a datalayer called VirtualPageView, and pass the corresponding url with "/variant" and the title with "Variant".
4. When the datalayer fires, I send a new Pageview with the variant information.

**The problem**

The experiment is running right, but when a user gets the B variant of the experiment and procceed to a subdomain of our websites to place an order, it seems that it's somehow running another test, and happens to the user get the A variation.

We are trying to persist the original session and the client Id through the domain and subdomain, in order to the user that saw the different logo, continue in his way to order.

I saw this page about [Running Experiments across Subdomains](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2658140?hl=en), but its about the Classic Analytics and the classic experiment, and we are using the Universal Analytics with the Content Experiment without redirects.

I don't know if my explanation was clear enough, so if someone have doubts, please ask me. I don't have a profound knowledge of Google Analytics or the Content Experiments either. So, if you have a better way to do this, please, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to our problem. We agreed to use the experiment only in the pages of the main domain, so I can change the content otherwise in the pages of the subdomain:

1. When a user visits our main domain, through Google Tag Manager, I created a cookie that says what the result of the variation chosen for the user (0 for the original and 1 for the variation).
2. When this user goes to our subdomain to place an order, still via GTM I check the cookie to see its value. If its equal to 1 (a variation), I change the logo and the menu, according to our previous configuration, and I send a virtual pageview to help us check the data.

Until now, this is working properly.